# Calculating non additive measure at the particular grouping level MDX

Tags: mdx

I've faced a issue with MDX query, that I don't know how to workaround. I have following query:

```
SELECT
 {
     [Measures].[Cost],
     [Measures].[Non additive]
 } ON COLUMNS,

 NON EMPTY 
 {
     [Organization].[Organization Name].[Organization Name].MEMBERS
     *[Time].[Month].[Month].MEMBERS
     *[Region].[City].[City].MEMBERS
 } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

And I would like to display "[Measures].[Non additive]" not at the lowest grouping level, but at the Organization Level. Is it possible?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you say at the organization level, do you mean like District, Region, etc?  So if org 1 is a part of Region A, you want the row that shows org 1 cost to show Region A's non additive value?

Comment: I just what to calculate this non additive measure at only one grouping level. In my example I would like to return values in non additive measure the same as it would be without [Time].[Month].[Month].MEMBERS and [Region].[City].[City].MEMBERS (only Organization attribute).

Answer (score 1):

When I have a measure I don't walways want to display, I make a copy of it and include a test for the level of the current cell.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[My New Measure Name] 
AS 'IIF(IsLeaf([Organization].currentMember), NULL, [Measures].[Non additive])'
SELECT
 {
     [Measures].[Cost],
     [Measures].[My New Measure Name]
 } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY 
 {
     [Organization].[Organization Name].[Organization Name].MEMBERS
     *[Time].[Month].[Month].MEMBERS
     *[Region].[City].[City].MEMBERS
 } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

The new measure tests whether the Organisation member is at the leaf level (the bottom of the hierarchy). If so it returns blank. If not, it returns the value of the old measure.

If you want more control, test if `[Organisation].level = [Organisation].levels(1)` and vary the number to detect which level you want (lower levels are higher numbers).